# Modelstate always throws invalid datetime error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about Date validations in Asp.net MVC4.
I am using Data annotations for Date validations as follows

```
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [AllowHtml]
   [DisplayFormat(HtmlEncode = false, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]      
   [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
   public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Next, in Html page, i am using following in MVC Html form

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserSettings.DateOfBirth, 
                          String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
                          model.UserSettings.DateOfBirth), 
                       new { id = "DoB", @class = "brth-ipt" })
```

Lastly, i am using a Jquery Date picker as follows

```
$(function () {
    $("#DoB").datepicker("destroy");
    $("#DoB").datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        beforeShow: customRange,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",  //"mm-dd-yy",
        firstDay: 1,
        changeFirstDay: false,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-150:+0"
    });
});
```

My problem is, when I select a date from datepicker, it is displayed as mm/dd/yyyy format and it works fine.

But when I load the page again to edit the form, it is displaying in mm-dd-yyyy format. Now, when i save the form without chaging the previous date (mm-dd-yyyy format), I am not able to save the form as Data annotation vaidation is throwing me an error. "Date is not in valid format".

I am not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth:")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

As far as i know, you wouldn't even need to use `Jquery Date picker`. The framework comes with built in helper to pick your dates.

**In your View**

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth )
    </div>
```

**This is tested in Google Chrome**

Answer (score 0):

`Html.TextBoxFox()` doesn't take `[DisplayFormat]` into account. To utilize this attribute and achieve your goal you may use

```
Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserSettings.DateOfBirth, new {id = "DoB", @class = "brth-ipt"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing and finally found how to fix my problem.
I made this data annotation in ViewModel

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

and this code in my date picker < div >

```
<div class="input-group date" id="mydatepicker" data-date-format="MM-dd-yyyy">
   <input asp-for="MyDate" type="text" class="form-control" />
   <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

and I put this code in jquery to send via ajax

```
$('#calender-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
   todayBtn: true,
   calendarWeeks: true,
   todayHighlight: true,
   autoclose: true,
}).datepicker('update', new Date());
```

Funny when I changed data-date-format from "mm-dd-yyyy",
which gives me invalid model state, to "MM-dd-yyyy" everything became valid.