# ModelState is invalid with DateTimeOffset + MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an issue with model state with datetimeoffset.
Saw the answers at :[Modelstate always throws invalid datetime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838760/modelstate-always-throws-invalid-datetime-error) but these doesnt solve my problem.

I have FromDate in model:

```
[Required, Display(Name = "From")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTimeOffset FromDate { get; set; }
```

I am showing it in my view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(O => O.FromDate)
```

-- start-- input data-val="true" id="FromDate" name="FromDate" type="datetime" class="datetime"      data-datetime="" value ="@Model.FromDate.ToString("r")" ---end

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(O => O.FromDate)
</div>
```

Changing the datetime value in jquery to local time in jquery:

```
if ($(this.element).val() != "") {
            // If we wont specify time on recreate then time sliders will stay unchanged.
            //  we manipulate datepicker value and value of input to display differently.
            //  LLLL--> Thursday, April 18 2013 1:20 PM
            //  L --> 04/18/2013
            //  LT --> 8:30 PM
           this._Input.datepicker("setDate", new Date(moment($(this.element).val()).format("LLLL")));
           this._Input.val(moment($(this.element).val()).format("L LT"));
        }
```

However when I edit and save, I am getting "FromDate is not valid" exception.

"The value 'Fri Jun 14 05:30:00 UTC+0530 2013' is not valid for From."

can somebody pls advise how to solve?

Model Binder:

```
protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        //var displayFormat = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString;

        string s = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("FromDate").AttemptedValue;
        string value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ThruDate").AttemptedValue;
        DateTimeOffset from;
        DateTimeOffset thru;
        if (s.IndexOf("UTC") != -1)
        {
              from = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\"zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else
        {
            from = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss \"GMT\"", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        }

        if (value.IndexOf("UTC") != -1)
            thru = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\"zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        else
            thru = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss \"GMT\"zzz \"(India Standard Time)\"", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);



        return PrFactory.Create(Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("PartyRoleTypeId").AttemptedValue),
            Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("PartyId").AttemptedValue),
            from,
            Convert.ToBoolean(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("IsSoftDeleted").AttemptedValue),
            new Party(),
            new PartyRoleType(),
           thru);

        //return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
```

Comment: I still didnt get any suggestionss!! :_(

Comment: I suggest you temporarily remove the DisplayFormat attribute to see if DateTimeOffset will even map to your field entry. I'm not sure what differences between DateTime and DateTimeOffset are but they are different struct types. That's where I would start...

Comment: without displayformat attribute also it will not get mapped, so only I am using displayformat attribute, still it is not working

Comment: Do you have any custom model binders in your solution? Or are you using a default model binder?

Comment: yes i do have, added to the question

Comment: I am not sure but try Setting Config like <globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" /> Or <globalization uiCulture="en-AU" culture="en-AU" />

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a custom binder? What I mean is are you doing custom binding for a specific reason or just because? If yes, then what is the reason why you're doing it?

Comment: my dates are in UTC format.I need to convert those to datetimeoffset before saving.so I am doing those in model binder before calling controller.do you see any flaws?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a *localized* date format coming out of momentjs? Localized for display is fine, but when sending to your server it should probably just be `.format()` to send it as ISO format.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply.yes for display purpose we are using moment.how can i convert it when i click on save, im new to jquery so only asking, do i need to write any other custom script?