# Invalid date from MVC4 model with datetimeoffset date

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am still facing problems with datetimeoffset values.

I have the below two dates, with FromDate have no issues.
With ThruDate, when I update and save I am getting ThruDate is not valid date.
Have raised a ques, [ModelState is invalid with DateTimeOffset + MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403792/modelstate-is-invalid-with-datetimeoffset-mvc4), but didnt get any answers.

```
[Required, Display(Name = "From")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT}")]
    public System.DateTimeOffset FromDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Thru")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz '(India Standard Time)'}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> ThruDate { get; set; }
```

However, the ThruDate format that I am using in model binder is working fine:

```
 if (value.IndexOf("UTC") != -1)
            thru = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"UTC\"zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        else
            thru = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss \"GMT\"zzz \"(India Standard Time)\"", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But this is not working in model DataFormatString and so is my modelstate is invalid.
can somebody advise what is wrong here?

Comment: does it make it back to your controller? if so, what kind of value does it post?

Comment: @user1778606 - it posts back to controller the date as "Tue Aug 20 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)". I am unable to get it validated in my controller as ModelState.Isvalid.