# Convert local time to UTC time in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a mvc to which we are rendering datetimeoffset value as UTC and showing it as local date time from datetime picker from jquery on the screen:

convertion of utc to local in jQuery

```
this._Input.val(moment($(this.element).val()).format("L LT"));
```

but when I save it back to database, I have to convert this value again to UTC.
can somebody advise how can I do that plss?

Comment: formatting the value for viewing purposes and sending/saving it are two different things

Comment: thats what my question. How can i save it back to database as datetimeoffset value.

Comment: Process is on the server side with whatever language you are using, PHP, Java,... They all have utilities to work with date/time.

Comment: please see my actual problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417861/invalid-date-from-mvc4-model-with-datetimeoffset-date, since i didnt get any answers i posted it here again